# Generic logger vs. exception pattern

Tags: c++, exception, logging

Consider a class `foo` which has one or more functions which can report failure either through a logger or by throwing an exception if no logger was provided:

```cpp
struct logger
{
    // ...
};

struct foo
{
    void set_logger(std::shared_ptr<logger> logger) { m_logger = std::move(logger); }

    bool bar(const std::filesystem::path& path)
    {
        // Check path validity
        if (not std::filesystem::exists(path) {
            if (m_logger) {
                m_logger->warn("path does not exist.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                throw std::runtime_error("path does not exists.");
            }
        }

        // Some random operation
        try {
            // Do something here that might throw
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            if (m_logger) {
                m_logger->warn("operation bar failed.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<logger> m_logger;
};
```

This does not only look ugly but is extremely error prone and as more functions are added to `foo` code will be repeditive.

Is there any kind of pattern or paradigm to abstract this logic away? Some kind of wrapper template I can construct to use inside `foo`'s various functions when error reporting is needed?

Anything up to C++20 would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your error case handling seems to follow the same structure, you could add a simple function that will do just that:

```
bool log_or_throw(logger * logger_, std::string const& message, std::exception const& exception) {
    if (logger_) {
        logger_->warn(message);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

And then you can change your error handling to a single line, probably making the flow a lot more readable:

```
if (not std::filesystem::exists(path) {
    return log_or_throw(m_logger, "path does not exist.", std::runtime_error("path does not exists."));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any kind of pattern or paradigm to abstract this logic away? Some kind of wrapper template I can construct to use inside foo's various functions when error reporting is needed?

One thing you could do is to simply remove all the `else { throw... }` code and provide a default logger that throws an exception containing the logged message. If the client provides a different logger, fine, your code will use that; if not, it uses the default one. This scheme eliminates about half your error handling code and simplifies the flow while providing the same behavior, which seems like a positive outcome.

It's important to remember that logging a message is different from throwing an exception: it's often useful to be able to log a message that doesn't stop the flow of the program. So be sure to give your logger class methods that log *without* throwing as well; you might use a different log level for messages that are equivalent to exceptions.